# Regex to match for all occurrences except when only one exists

Tags: regex

I have this sample string `111:222:333`. From this, I need to extract all three `:` separated numbers. The output should find three matches - `111` and `222` and `333`.

I use this regex to achieve this: `(?<=^|:)(\d+)(?=:|$)`.

However, I need this regex to match only when there are at least 2 matches. Hence, `111` should not match, but `111,222,...` should.

I cannot use standard split functions in Java, because my use case mandates the regular expression being dynamically read from the database.

How do I enforce 'at least two matches' condition?

Comment: Try `(?<=\G(?!^):|^(?=\d+(?::\d+)+$))\d+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=\G(?!^):|^(?=\d+(?::\d+)+$))\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IipF1O/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=\G(?!^):|^(?=\d+(?::\d+)+$))` - a positive lookbehind that matches either of the two alternative locations in string:

  - `\G(?!^):` - a position after a previous successful match and `:`
  - `|` - or
  - `^(?=\d+(?::\d+)+$))` - start of a string that is followed with 1+ digits and then 1 or more sequences of `:` and 1+ digits up to the string end
- `\d+` - consuming 1 or more digits